# Can someone explain to me why I am getting a Stack Overflow on this?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[Updated ( Fixed ) Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/nightstalker22/CLLfy/4/)

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

It's a simple customized Title that displays when mousing over elements. It breaks after several displays.

```
function showtitle(title) {

  $('.button').bind('mousemove', function(e){
    $('.message').fadeIn(600);
    var message = $('.message').css({
      'position' : 'absolute',
      'left' : e.pageX,
      'top'  : e.pageY + 25
    });
    var print = title;
    $('.message').html('<span>' + print + '</span>');

  });

}
function hidetitle() {
  $('.message').hide();
}
```

Comment: Try to do this with CSS only, toggling a class and using CSS3 transitions.

Comment: If you really need to use JS, use mouseenter event, instead of mouseover. You are killing js engine with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You’re rebinding the `mousemove` event every time the mouse moves over the element, but never taking it off.

```
function moveHandler(e) {
    $('.message').fadeIn(600);

    var message = $('.message').css({
        position: 'absolute',
        left: e.pageX,
        top: e.pageY + 25
    });

    $('.message').empty().append($('<span>', {text: title}));
}

function showtitle(title) {
    $('.button').bind('mousemove', moveHandler);
}

function hidetitle() {
    $('.message').hide();
    $('.button').unbind('mousemove', moveHandler);
}
```

You could also keep the `mousemove` event on all the time and use CSS’s `:hover` to show and hide the tooltip.

I’m guessing this isn’t because of the browser’s event loop, but rather because of either jQuery’s handling of events or jQuery’s queuing of animations. You should also fade in the appropriate message *once*, in `showtitle`, and set its text at the same time; not every time the mouse moves.

Comment: Thank you sir. I am still getting a grip on listeners. This is working beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

It may be because you are binding mousemove to an anonymous function. Every time that event fires the function is being created again. Try defining the function before binding it to the event.

Comment: That's not true. He is binding an anonymous, true, but the real cause is that he binds the anonymous everytime he mouses over, which eventually leads to more than dozens of event handlers per mouseover, ultimately causing a call stack overflow.

Comment: Thanks Derija93 for the info.